# No result defined for action com.ccarc.Contact and result success

Tags: struts2, struts2-namespace

I must be missing something here.  I have the following struts.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <struts>
       <package name="myName" namespace="/myName" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="contact" class="com.ccarc.Contact">
           <result>/jsp/Contact.jsp</result>
           <result name="success">/jsp/Contact.jsp</result>
        </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

I am getting the following error
`No result defined for action com.ccarc.Contact and result success`

and for my class I have the following (I took out some of the code to make it more readable)

```
package com.ccarc;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class Contact extends ActionSupport {

    public String execute() {
        System.out.println("in the action");

        return SUCCESS; // as defined by Action interface as "success"
    }
}
```

I have looked around and have not found an answer, most are asked by people that forgot the name in the result (but as you can see I have the name success listed)

Also my web.xml file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <display-name>myApp</display-name>

  <filter>
     <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.ccarc</param-value>
     </init-param>
</filter>

  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I should also note that I have tried chaning the class in the struts.xml to just "Contact" and I still get the same error message.

I have also verified that /WebConent/classes/com/ccarc/Contact.class does exist.

Also I should note in the console of eclipse I am seeing the out put from the class, so the object is being called, but when it returns from the class is where the issue is coming up.

Here is the full stack trace

```
Aug 1, 2012 1:33:25 AM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher serviceAction
SEVERE: Could not find action or result
No result defined for action com.ccarc.Contact and result success
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:350)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:253)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:150)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:48)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:105)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:83)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:74)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:127)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:107)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:206)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:115)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:143)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:121)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:170)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:123)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:50)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:504)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: why  `<result>/jsp/Contact.jsp</result><result name="success">/jsp/Contact.jsp</result>` has been defined 2 times? when you do not define any result name default is always success

Comment: no good reason.  I have removed the `<result>/jsp/Contact.jsp</result>` and left just the success one.  The reason I am leaving the success one instead of the default one, is I would guess having the success one would be a bit more readable.

Comment: can you show complete stack error as well the URL you are hitting?

Comment: I have added the stack trace to the original question, and the URL is a local host, so you will not be able to reach it, but here is the URL http://http://localhost:8080/FieldDayLogger/contact.action

Comment: Change the namespace to "/" in your struts.xml

Comment: HashimR, could you do that as an answer so I can accept it.  It worked.  Also could you explain why it is that way so I can figure out why I was thinking incorrectly? thanks

Comment: @mpop: i strongly suggest you to have understanding of [/namespace-configuration](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/namespace-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Change your URL to:

```
http://localhost:8080/FieldDayLogger/myName/contact.action
```

Or if you want to use the same URL then change the namespace to "/" in your struts.xml.

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-namespace-configuration-example-and-explanation/) is a good link to understand namespace configuration and explanation. :)

Comment: why to change namespace to `/`? in S2 you can choose any namespace and all you need to know to map that and how they work

Comment: Thanks HashimR it is apperciated

Comment: @HashimR: i agree, please remove first line from your answer, namespace does not mean to use '/' always

Comment: Just a follow up I went back to the namespace being myName and the URL you suggested and it worked.  Just so others can see that your second suggestion also worked.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi: First line was actually a comment. :)

Comment: that's fine,my whole comments was to make sure that things should be as per the way they work :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason for this is the URL  `http://localhost:8080/FieldDayLogger/contact.action`
in you mapping file  `<package name="myName" namespace="/myName" extends="struts-default">` you have defined you namespace as `/myName` while you are not using in your URL.

Struts2 have a mechanism by which it looks for the namespace and if nothing found will go to the default one, in your case its unable to find it.

> Namespace are not hierarchical like a file system path. There is one namespace level. For example if the URL /barspace/myspace/bar.action is requested, the framework will first look for namespace /barspace/myspace. If the action does not exist at /barspace/myspace, the search will immediately fall back to the default namespace "". The framework will not parse the namespace into a series of "folders". In the Namespace Example, the bar action in the default namespace would be selected.

I strongly suggest you to look at the doc of namespace and see how it works

- [namespace-configuration](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/namespace-configuration.html)

another solution is if you are creating action in your from tag or other such tag there is a property namely `namespace` add `/myName` to that.

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess "contact" like is a key word in Struts2. 
please rename com.ccarc.Contact to com.ccarc.MyContact and try again...

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use namespace always.
you can use namespace="/" if the files are to be accessed is inside WebContent or you can use any name other than "/" according to your directory structure of file.

Try the following.

```
<package name="myName" namespace="/myName" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="contact" class="com.ccarc.Contact">
           <result name="success">jsp/Contact.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing definition in tiles.xml:

```
<tiles-definitions>

...

  <definition name="foobar" template="/jsp/template.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="viewId" value="foobar"/>
    <put-attribute name="workArea"  value="/jsp/foobar.jsp"/>
  </definition>

...

</tiles-definitions>
```

check the docs: https://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-tiles-spring-mvc-webapp-tiles-xml-config.html